# Capture compiler version and processor architecture at compile time

Tags: c

I currently display the version details of my programs using code that looks like this (Note - VERSION, BUILD, and COMMIT_ID are pre-defined).

```
void v_version() /* Display version information */
{
   fprintf(stdout, "%s: Version %s %s", FILENAME, VERSION, COMMIT_ID);
   if (__DATE__[4] == ' ') fprintf(stdout, " 0"); else fprintf(stdout, " %c", __DATE__[4]);
   fprintf(stdout, "%c %c%c%c %s %s", __DATE__[5],
      __DATE__[0], __DATE__[1], __DATE__[2], &__DATE__[9], __TIME__ );
   fprintf(stdout, " (build: %s)\n", BUILD );
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
my-program: Version 0.8 [Commit ID: 5c18dcf] 14 Oct 23 22:26:41 (build: 0092)
```

However, what I'd like to be able to do is to also capture as much detail about the operating system, command line used including flags (like `-fcommon -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99`), the compiler version, and processor architecture of the system that was used to compile the code as possible.

I know I can do this for most UNIX/Linux systems by defining a some macros in the make file and using these in my code but I want to avoid this approach if possible so that the information is captured even if the source is compiled without using the make file.

The answer below doesn't actually answer the question but does suggest some improvements so I've updated my code as follows:

```
void v_version() /* Display version information */
{
   fprintf(stdout, "%s: Version %s %s", NAME, VERSION, COMMIT_ID);
   fprintf(stdout, " %02d %3.3s %s %5.5s", atoi(&__DATE__[4]), &__DATE__[0], &__DATE__[9], __TIME__ );
   fprintf(stdout, " (build: %s)\n", BUILD );
}
```

Comment: I doubt it is possible to do it in any portable way. Your suggestion of defining macros in the makefile is the best solution. And if you have a makefile, why would you ever build your code "by hand", whatever that means?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. However, almost all compilers have predefined tokens that identify them and (some of) the flags used, the platform targeted and other information. Take a look at the headers for some decent third-party libraries and look for the (probably numerous) `#if defined(__MSC_VER) ... #elif defined (__GNUC__)` and similar conditional blocks.

Comment: It does not cover everything but I may borrow some of the ideas from this header file  https://github.com/PhilipLudington/poshlib/blob/master/posh.h

Answer (score 2):

Please don't torture your readers.

Simplification of outputting the date of compilation (offering two styles):

```
static int monthOrd( char cp[] ) { // month ordinal from month name
    return "DIE@CB@LJF@HAG@K"[ cp[1]/4&7 ^ cp[2]*2 &0xF ] &0xF;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *p = __DATE__; // "MMM DD YYYY"
                        //  01234567890 <= offsets

    printf( "%02d %3.3s %2.2s\n", atoi(p+4), p, p+9 ); // "DD MMM YY"

    printf( "%4.4s/%02d/%02d\n", p+7, monthOrd(p), atoi(p+4) ); // "YYYY/MM/DD"

    return 0;
}
```

Caveat: `monthOrd()` works by hashing the English month names as 7 bit ASCII. I don't know if compilers might use other (locale specific) month names.

Comment: I have to wonder if `monthord()` is a simplification ...?    (Crufty - yes, simple - to some people maybe, but not me!).   If I came across that in my code again in 15 years time I doubt I'd be able to remember how it worked, and don't think I could debug it.  

I do accept that your use of fixed width format strings does simplify the date display however, I'm not going to mark this as an answer as although it is interesting, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @MikeT. No worries. I agree; this does not provide more tokens to burn into a binary. :-) Just wanted to pass along something less torturous (#1) that reformats __DATE__. #2 and `monthOrd()` are just along for the ride. "Crufty"??? It's a purpose built hash function combined with a small LUT... "Crufty" only to those mired in dogma... Cheers! :-)